# N Records Taken R at a time Algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, loops, batch-file, computer-science

If I know I have n records, and I want to do something to a group of r records at a time (basically do stuff to n in batches because n is really large), what is the algorithm for that? Any language is OK (though I'm using PHP).

The algorithm should keep in mind that in the final iteration, there may not be enough records to create a complete group of r.

```
Recall: to find the total number of r combinations from a set of n records, 
use the combination formula:

C(n,r) = n! / r!(n-r)!
```

-- Edit --
In case others are interested: I have a CSV (string) with about 10K rows. I was looking for the most efficient way of processing each row of the CSV in chunks of X.

For example, I need to send data from the CSV to a 3rd party via API. The API only allows sending X records at once (which is why I need the chunking).

Comment: I also don't understand. Based on your initial question, combinations (C(n,r)) are not relevant. I suspect you're asking more than your words say.

Comment: do you want to get all the possibilities (`C(n,r)`) or just chunks of `r` from an array of size `n`? If it's the first one, I'd recommend you rethink it a bit, because, for example, `C(100, 40)` is approximately `1.37 * 10^28`, and I doubt you have the time to wait for that to finish.

Comment: To simplify, I just need the chunks. If I have 100 records and I need chunks of 20 records a piece, that's 5 chunks.

Comment: @Joshua McGinnis - Are you looking for SQL to query chunks from a table?  Are you asking for code to access array elements one chunk at a time?  Something else???

Comment: This is as simple as grabbing `($i * $s, ($i+1) * $s - 1)` (inclusive) where `$i` is the iteration and `$s` is the chunk size. Yes, the last chunk may be smaller, but that is generally trivial to detect. If you need a precise solution, it would be helpful to know more about how the input is being stored (e.g., MySQL?).

Comment: I updated the question with more information in case someone wanted to offer another opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

```
$chunks = array_chunk($arr, $r);
foreach($chunks as $chunk)
{
   deal_with($chunk);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I didn't realize there was array_chunk().